# Android Action Bar Icon Opacity

Tags: android

[image]

Hi There,

I am new to Android programming and using Android studio for my development.
As you can see from the screenshot, I've got a "refresh icon" but it is more of a gray color and I want to make it white. Here is my style. There is no gray color used in the style and I don't know which item I should use to override its gray color.. Please help!

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Coin</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Coin</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Coin</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Coin</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Coin</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_coin</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_coin</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Coin</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Coin" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_coin</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_coin</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_coin</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Coin</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Coin" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_coin</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Coin</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I also tried "android:textColorSecondary" but no luck

Comment: I think problem with your icon.

Comment: you need a revised Refresh.png drawable that is white with no transparency, this isn't a styles.xml issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Consider using something like [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C60) to create an icon with the desired opacity.

They already have a bunch of free to use (CCA 3.0) icons (including the same refresh icon you're using) and you can easily modify the opacity by modifying the opacity controller next to the **'Custom color'** option.